# Why does the SELinux policy say /init is unlabeled on Android Things?

Tags: android, init, android-things, libselinux, seandroid

I'm trying to port Android Things to a binary code compatible hardware platform. What I've done so far is to convert the `system.img` sparse file to an ext4 partition which I copied to an SD card.

Now I'm stuck at the point where `/init` is starting it's second stage. More precisely the SELinux policy denies to read `selinux_version` and `file_contexts.bin` and denies to execute `/init` a second time.

Now the interesting part is that the `tcontext` says the file is `unlabeled`, but why and how can I solve this?